# Android Studio compile error (Gradle)

Tags: android, android-studio

I started a new project on Android Studio with "Create Activity" checked and then selected "Balnk Activity" with navigation type "Scroolable Tabs + Swipe".

Then I tried to modify the generated "fragment_main_dummy.xml" layout to set an id to the root Relative Layout.

When I try to run the project I get the following compile error:

```
...\Test1\build\res\all\debug\layout\fragment_main_dummy.xml
Gradle: String types not allowed (at 'id' with value 'test').
```

Even if I reset the changes the error persists.
Only by manually editing the mentioned file can the problem be resolved.

So the questions are:

- Why are all the res files copyed to the build\res\all\debug folder?
- Why aren't these files updated when I modify the actual file in the src folder?

Comment: The problem seems to have been solved on later releases.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add in the string id "**@+id/**" in your example "**@+id/test**"
Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is how Intellij manages resources, it helps with id lookups etc I don't know the specifics, but it is not AndroidStudio but IntelliJ as a whole that works this way with the R file (might help you google it).

The file won't be modified as these are build files, so will be updated when you recompile the project. (i.e. when you run / deploy to a device / build an APK).

I thought IntelliJ auto built projects, so maybe you have turned this off? You can test this with File Menu: Build > Rebuild Project